# Combine data.frames summing up values of identical columns in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, aggregate

I have 3 data frames (rows: sites, columns:species name) of species abundances within sites. Row numbers are identical, but column numbers differ as not all species are in all three data frames. I would like to merge them into one data frame with abundances of identical species summed up. For example:

data.frame1

```
       Sp1  Sp2  Sp3  Sp4
site1   1    2    3    1
site2   0    2    0    1
site3   1    1    1    1
```

data.frame2

```
       Sp1  Sp2  Sp4
 site1  0    1    2
 site2  1    2    0
 site3  1    1    1
```

data.frame3

```
       Sp1  Sp2  Sp5  Sp6
 site1  0    1    1    1     
 site2  1    1    1    5
 site3  2    0    0    0
```

What I want to have is something like:

```
       Sp1  Sp2  Sp3  Sp4  Sp5  Sp6
 site1  1    4    3    3    1    1
 site2  2    5    0    1    1    5
 site3  4    2    1    2    0    0
```

I guess i'd have to work with merge, but so far my attempts have failed to get what I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `aggregate` better than `merge` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd use `plyr`'s `rbind.fill` like this:

```
pp <- cbind(names=c(rownames(df1), rownames(df2), rownames(df3)), 
                        rbind.fill(list(df1, df2, df3)))

#   names Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp5 Sp6
# 1 site1   1   2   3   1  NA  NA
# 2 site2   0   2   0   1  NA  NA
# 3 site3   1   1   1   1  NA  NA
# 4 site1   0   1  NA   2  NA  NA
# 5 site2   1   2  NA   0  NA  NA
# 6 site3   1   1  NA   1  NA  NA
# 7 site1   0   1  NA  NA   1   1
# 8 site2   1   1  NA  NA   1   5
# 9 site3   2   0  NA  NA   0   0
```

Then, aggregate with `plyr's` `ddply` as follows:

```
ddply(pp, .(names), function(x) colSums(x[,-1], na.rm = TRUE))
#   names Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp5 Sp6
# 1 site1   1   4   3   3   1   1
# 2 site2   2   5   0   1   1   5
# 3 site3   4   2   1   2   0   0
```

Comment: I had a solution in mind and I promise it was not this elegant.  +1

Comment: @eugenego You can mark the check mark next to the solution that best answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to use `melt/cast` from `reshape2`. Here is an unsophisticated example:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T, text="
    Sp1  Sp2  Sp3  Sp4
    site1   1    2    3    1
    site2   0    2    0    1
    site3   1    1    1    1")

df2 <- read.table(header=T, text="
       Sp1  Sp2  Sp4
 site1  0    1    2
 site2  1    2    0
 site3  1    1    1")

df3 <- read.table(header=T, text="
       Sp1  Sp2  Sp5  Sp6
 site1  0    1    1    1     
 site2  1    1    1    5
 site3  2    0    0    0")

df1$site <- rownames(df1)
df2$site <- rownames(df2)
df3$site <- rownames(df3)

DF <- rbind(melt(df1,id="site"),melt(df2,id="site"),melt(df3,id="site"))
dcast(data=DF,formula=site ~ variable,fun.aggregate=sum)

   site Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp5 Sp6
1 site1   1   4   3   3   1   1
2 site2   2   5   0   1   1   5
3 site3   4   2   1   2   0   0
```

In short, we use site designation as an additional variable, and convert each dataframe to long format, subsequently joining them into a single dataframe. The latter contains all the values in the long format. With `dcast` we create the dataframe you require, sites being in rows (left side of the formula), variables being in columns (right side of the formula). The sum function is used on the variables for which multiple cells are produced.

Of course, the code can be extended to more general case with loops or *apply functions.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the options available, here are two more that stick with base R.

**First option**: *Wide aggregation (sort of)*

```
temp <- cbind(df1, df2, df3)
temp
#       Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp1 Sp2 Sp4 Sp1 Sp2 Sp5 Sp6
# site1   1   2   3   1   0   1   2   0   1   1   1
# site2   0   2   0   1   1   2   0   1   1   1   5
# site3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   0   0   0
sapply(unique(colnames(temp)), 
       function(x) rowSums(temp[, colnames(temp) == x, drop = FALSE]))
#       Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp5 Sp6
# site1   1   4   3   3   1   1
# site2   2   5   0   1   1   5
# site3   4   2   1   2   0   0
```

**Second option**: *semi-wide to long to wide*

Conceptually, this is similar to Maxim. K's answer: Get the data in a long form, and it makes it much easier to manipulate things:

```
> temp1 <- t(cbind(df1, df2, df3))
> # You'll get a warning in the next step
> # Safe to ignore though...
> temp2 <- data.frame(var = rownames(temp), stack(data.frame(temp)))
Warning message:
In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 5,6,7,8,9 --> row.names NOT used
> xtabs(values ~ ind + var, temp2)
       var
ind     Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp5 Sp6
  site1   1   4   3   3   1   1
  site2   2   5   0   1   1   5
  site3   4   2   1   2   0   0
```

Comment: I have used the "First option" and it have worked perfect and faster than proposed answer for a "temp1" data frame of 14500 x 130000 dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Arun's answer:
Create a 'template'  array with all the columns you'll need

```
Rgames> bbar<-data.frame('one'=rep(0,3),'two'=rep(0,3),'three'=rep(0,3))
Rgames> bbar
  one two three
1  0    0    0
2   0    0    0
3   0    0    0
```

Then, given each of your data frames like

```
Rgames> bar1<-data.frame('one'=c(1,2,3),'two'=c(4,5,6))
Rgames> bar1
  one two
1   1   4
2   2   5
3   3   6
```

Create an expanded dataframe:

```
Rgames> newbar1<-bbar
Rgames> for (jj in names(bar) )  newbar1[[jj]]<-bar[[jj]]
Rgames> newbar1
  one two three
1   1   4    0
2   2   5    0
3   3   6    0
```

Then sum all such expanded data frames.  Clumsy but simple.