# R Merge tables with one identifier, and other columns with same name will add up

Tags: r, merge

I am currently have multiple tables need to merge. For example, I have tbl_1, tbl_2, and tbl_3. And I want to reach the final result as result table.

```
tbl_1:
ID  trx_1  Cre_counts Deb_counts 
1    10        9        8
2    5         6        5
3    10        4        3

tbl_2:
ID  trx_2  Unk_counts Deb_counts 
1    10       1        2
2    5        6        5
3    10       3        7

tbl_3:
ID  trx_3  Unk_counts Ckc_counts 
1    3        4        4
2    2        4        3
3    8        7        6

result:
ID  trx_1  tx_2 trx_3 Cre_counts Deb_counts Unk_counts Ckc_counts 
1    10     10      3         9        10       5           4
2    5      5       2         6        10       10          3
3    10     10      8         4        10       10          6
```

I have tries merge three tables by "ID", but the column name will change to Deb_counts.x, Deb_counts.y... I can use transform(), rowSums() to take some extra step to make it work. But I am wondering is there a easier way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: you don't just want to merge, you want to merge some values and add other values, you need to proceed in at least 2 steps

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Currently, the steps I am taking are more than two steps. I am merge all the tables first, and then use rowSums() to add all the columns I want to add. Then, delete old columns. Just wondering if you know any easier way to do it? maybe just 2 steps.

Comment: Hi, hope this link helps, almost same question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018863/combine-data-frames-summing-up-values-of-identical-columns-in-r

Comment: Hi, wen. Thank you for the link. It did checked out that website before. The problem is that my row number are not identical. The solution posted is not working for me. But I will keep modifying.

Comment: I posted a 2-step way, though second step is a bit long...

Comment: Then you need modify your question , as far as I thought , they are the same

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most elegant but here is a way:

First, you need to put your tables into a list:

```
l_tbl <- mget(ls(pattern="^tbl"))
```

Then you go through the list, working with 2 tables at a time, thanks to `Reduce`, first adding the common columns, then merging:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {
          col_com <- setdiff(intersect(names(x), names(y)), "ID")
          if(length(col_com)) {
               x[, col_com] <- x[, col_com] + y[, col_com]
               y <- y[, !(names(y) %in% col_com)] # you only keep the "not common" columns in the second table
          }
               return(merge(x, y, by="ID"))
       }, l_tbl)

  ID trx_1 Cre_counts trx_3 Ckc_counts trx_2 Deb_counts Unk_counts
1  1    10          9     3          4    10         10          5
2  2     5          6     2          3     5         10         10
3  3    10          4     8          6    10         10         10
```

Comment: I got a error in x[,col_com] + y[,col_com]: non-numeric argument to binary operator. Not sure the reason. The first step is good. I forget to mention. Not every two tables will have same column names, so sometimes, col_com will be character(0). Will that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @VeraShao that will not be a problem as I check if col_com has length at least one. I don't know why you get an error except if your common cols are not all numeric